# How to convert a string to a date in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the date and time in the following format in Excel:- 12Jun17/1802 How do I convert this to excel date and time format? I have tried Format Custom but I am unable to make this work.

Comment: Use string functions to format the string as something Excel will recognize as a date/time, then convert that value to a number.  The various formats will then work

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Please explain what a string function is.

Comment: You can find out about this, and much more, by using the Help function in Excel, or by using Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates and times as days and fractions of a day since 1/1/1900.  The string you show is being seen only as text.

One way to convert it is to use string functions to format it into something Excel will recognize as a date/time:

```
=LEFT(A2,2) & " " & MID(A2,3,3) & " " & MID(A2,6,2) & " " & TEXT(RIGHT(A2,4),"00\:00")
```

> --> 12 Jun 17 08:02

and then convert that to a number:

```
=--(LEFT(A2,2) & " " & MID(A2,3,3) & " " & MID(A2,6,2) & " " & TEXT(RIGHT(A2,4),"00\:00"))
```

You can now format that number with any of the date/time formats.

Comment: Your first formula works but the second is returning #VALUE! . Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Either your data is not as you presented; your system does not use the same spelling for months as is in your string; or you are doing something else incorrectly.  Since I am not at your computer, I really cannot tell.

Comment: If I use your second formula to convert 12Jun17/1802 it works however if I use your second formula to convert 12 Jun 17 18:02 I receive #VALUE. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The second formula converts a string of text ie the 12 characters of `12Jun17/1802` that looks like a date to what Excel holds internally as a date. The result of the formula is 42898.75139, which is the time in days since since Excel's "time zero". Applying an appropriate date time format to this result displays at as a recognisable date/time such as `12 Jun 17 18:02` or `12/06/2017 06:02  PM`. The formula only works on a string of text. If you enter `12 Jun 17 18:02` directly into a cell, Excel will automatically interpret this as a date not as text, so the formula will not work

Comment: @Anthony The purpose of the first formula was only to demonstrate the intermediate result, before surrounding the first formula with the double unary converted it to a number.  I thought it might clarify a bit how the formula works.  I am sorry that it confused you.  The second formula is what you should be using.  And you might find it instructive to use the formula evaluation tool in order to understand how it is working.